# How to highlight first cell of subsequent row on enter keypress after entering data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I've written a code to create a new row on enter keyup, when you're currently in the last row.

**Problem** - But the issue I am facing is that, when you type some data and then press enter key, it doesnt create a new row. (It goes to the first cell of the first row.)

I think the issue I am facing is because of the `"this.refresh();"` function which is being called under `"save"` function in the Kendo UI.

I just can't get rid of that function since I'm using an aggregate functionality which i need to sum up all the values in all the tabs in the jsfiddle posted here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aravind_93/Lw6awf6g/)

May I know if there is any way such that a new row is created as well as the first cell of the newly created row is highlighted.
PS: If there are 5 rows and I am currently in the 3rd row, if I press the enter key it should navigate to the subsequent row and highlight the first cell. (Since, in this case it is not the last row,I don't need to create a new row, but just navigate to the subsequent row on click.)

I've tried to make use of editable-cell properties, but nothing worked.

***So, in short my question is to navigate to the subsequent row and highlight the first cell on enter key press(after or before entering data) and to create a new row on enter key press and highlight it's first cell.***

```
save:function(e){

            this.refresh();

        }
```

^^This is the function responsible for refreshing the content of the Kendo Grid when data is entered.